# How to import physical constants from scipy.constants.physical_constants?

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy

I'm trying to import the `electron volt-joule relationship` from `scipy.constants.physical_constants` for use in a numerical physics problem. This is probably a very simple issue, or a misunderstanding of the physical_constants dictionary, but after googling for 2 hrs I'm still at a loss.

I've tried

`from scipy.constants.physical_constants import electron volt_joule relationship`

I also tried

`import scipy.constants.physical_constants["electron volt-joule relationship"]`

Which produces

`File "<ipython-input-22-7c2fb3ec2156>", line 3 import scipy.constants.physical_constants["electron volt-joule relationship"] ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Am I misunderstanding the use of these physical constants? From scipy.org documentation I'm seeing that they come in the form physical_constants[name] = (value, unit, uncertainty)

so I can get

`print(scipy.constants.physical_constants["electron volt-joule relationship"])`

to return

`(1.602176634e-19, 'J', 0.0)`

but even

`import scipy.constants.physical_constants`

returns an error of

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b4d34ca28080> in <module> 
----> 1 import scipy.constants.physical_constants

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.constants.physical_constants'
```

Is this constants library full of values you can reference the value, unit, and uncertainty of and not actually use in computations?

Comment: `from scipy.constants import physical_constants`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the original poster's import statement is not formatted correctly.
To get access to the constants include this import statement:

```
from scipy import constants
```

Then to access a specific constant, try:

```
print(constants.electron_volt)

returns:
1.602176634e-19
```

If the scipy package is not found, it can be added with:

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

As `'electron volt_joule relationship'` is one key inside a python dictionary called `scypy.constants.physical_constants`, it can not be imported, whereas the whole dictionary can be imported. As examples, let's load `scipy.constants` and `physical_constants`, and also, `astropy.constants`:

```
import scipy.constants as syc
import astropy.constants as ayc
from scipy.constants import physical_constants as pyc
```

Note that:

```
print(type(syc),type(ayc),type(pyc))
```

returns: `<class 'module'> <class 'module'> <class 'dict'>`. You can also investigate contents of `syc`, `ayc` and `pyc` with function `dir`, or to make it shorter, a lambda function I like to call `tab` defined as:

```
tab = lambda obj: [atr for atr in dir(obj) if '__' not in atr]
```

`tab(pyc)` will return atributes and methods of python dicts, like `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()`. Inside `pyc.keys()` there is one called `'electron volt_joule relationship'`, and as it happens with all `pyc` contents or keys, returns a tuple containing value, unit and uncertainty for this definition:

```
v,u,uc = pyc['electron volt_joule relationship']
```

so that v is a value, u is the physical unit and uc is the uncertainty.

```
print(f'1eV = {v}{u} \u00B1 {uc}{u}')
```

will print the relationship:

```
1eV = 1.602176634e-19J ± 0.0J
```

Note that according to scipy, there is no uncertainty for this definition. Note also that there is an eV directly under syc:

```
print(syc.eV)
1.602176634e-19
```

and it happens to be numerically identical to the absolute value of the electrical charge of one electron (firstly measured by Millikan in 1909), or the elementary charge, in Coulombs, also in `syc.elementary_charge`. At our example from `astropy`, `ayp` is a special class that gives us the physical units together with the constants values. To see it, just type `ayc.e` in a jupyter notebook, for instance:

```
ayc.e
1.6021766×10−19C
```

and:

```
print(ayc.e)
```

will give:

```
Name   = Electron charge
Value  = 1.6021766208e-19
Uncertainty  = 9.8e-28
Unit  = C
Reference = CODATA 2014
```

so that there are other important attributes under `ayc.e`:

```
print(f'{ayc.e.name} = {ayc.e.value}{ayc.e.unit} \u00B1 {ayc.e.uncertainty}{ayc.e.unit} ')
Electron charge = 1.6021766208e-19C ± 9.8e-28C
```

and we can see that according to `astropy`, there is a small uncertainty related with the elementary unit of electrical charge, that must be related with the eV to J relationship uncertainty by definition, after all.

Comment: Updating astropy, I noticed a newer definition on ayc.e, according to CODATA 2018, it's newest uncertaint is really zero! The updated value: 1.602176634e-19C.